# passing value to custom table from other View or page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have custom cell (TJourneyListCell ) on which i have some label i want to know how can I populate the table by entering more value from other view where i have Give user to enter his name and all this kind of think.when he enter the value it should show into table also.I just try this hard code value but I need more row ganrate at when user enter the value from other view .

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TJourneyListCell *cell = (id)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TJourneyListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.namelbl.text =@"My journey";
    cell.distancelbl.text = @"raji";
    cell.infolbl.text = @"pradeep"; 
    cell.timelbl.text = @"harish";
    cell.userimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Is this any who can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate [model object class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ModelObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH31-SW1) that stores your data.

Have generic view A and table view B access the properties of an instance of this model class.

Read up on Apple's documentation for the [Model-View-Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1) design pattern.

Comment: I have custom table then how can i pass value from other View page can you more explain me more

Answer (score 0):

You should send the information from your other view to your tableViewController by delegation :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18

In your delegateMethod (something like : userDidFinsihEnteringInformation:)
you can reload datas on your table :

```
 - (void)reloadData
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: But i have the custom table where i have custom cell (TJourneyListCell ). And i am new in this iphone field can you help me to understand with help sample code.